# HTML table with contenteditable in python

Tags: python, html, flask

I would like to create a HTML table with contenteditable fields from python. I am using python + flask. I have the data ready as a dictionary and needs to create a dynamic page and display the items. I was checking couple of modules like pyh and html.py. But looks like nothing is well suited for me. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this something you should try to solve using client-side techonlogies? Try looking into HTML/Javascript (maybe [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)).

Comment: Just a note to say that contenteditable table cells will not work in IE9 (or lower) or Opera. I believe Modernizr can get this working; alternatively you'd need contenteditable dividers inside the cells. `<td><div contenteditable="true"></div></td>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Jinja2 template. You write a template file which includes python code inserts (see [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) for the docs), and then render the template as the return value to a request method using the flask method. So you end your request method with `return render_template(args...)`.