# Using contenteditable in Python

Tags: python-3.x, contenteditable

I am currently building a todo app using Flask and would like to add the Edit functionality for each item in place, i.e. without opening any new window but edit it right there. I came across the **contenteditable** property, but I  want to know how to extract the edited value from this and send it to a Python function for storing it in the database.

Currently, I have set the property to true as follows:

```
<span contenteditable="true"> {{ todo.todoitem }} </span>
```

Double-clicking on it allows me to edit the value, however it does not get saved and reverts to the original value once I am done editing.

I found a similar question here:
[HTML table with contenteditable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026599/html-table-with-contenteditable-in-python), however I am not sure how to use a Jinja2 template to achieve this.

In what way can this be implemented?